# add post parameters to file_get_contents in php

Tags: php

I want to ask you how to add `POST` parameter to php file in `file_get_contents` function. I tried something like this, but its not working:

```
$getdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                'firstname'=>$firstname,
                'lastname' =>$lastname
            )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $getdata
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $this->body = file_get_contents('templates/email/email_after_registration.php', false, $context);
    echo 'content' . $this->body;
    exit();
```

In output is only 'content' and static html text, In 'templates/email/email_after_registration.php' I want also use  `$_POST['firstname']`, `$_POST['lastname']`, `$_POST['user_id']`, but they are empty :( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different solutions:

1) If you set second parameter as `false`

> Means that you are not using inclusion and you need the full path

```
file_get_contents('http://{HOST}/templates/email/email_after_registration.php', false, $context);
```

Have a look in detail [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

2) Use inclusion instead?

```
$_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$_POST['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_POST['lastname'] = $lastname;

ob_start();
include('templates/email/email_after_registration.php');
$this->body = ob_get_clean();
echo 'content' . $this->body;
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use cURL for this.